# Horizontal scrollable calendar view

Tags: android, calendar

I want to create horizontally scrollable calendar view like below image.
[image]

I have got some thirdparty libraries to create calendar view, but all those supports only normal calendar. I want minimized version of the calendar in horizontally scrollable and on click of a date the content should be updated.

Comment: Hey you can try my library. https://github.com/afreakyelf/HorizontalCalendarLibrary

This is a lot similar to what you require

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an old post but I want to share my findings

This library offers great customization, is written in Kotlin and support SDK >=21

[SingleRowCalendar GitHub](https://github.com/miso01/SingleRowCalendar)

And check [this](https://medium.com/@misosvec01/single-row-horizontal-calendar-has-never-been-easier-6ad989fafee8) Medium post for a step-by-step guide.

Here are some sample UIs you can easily produce

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: This library seems better than the one I accepted before, hence I am marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Is it compatible with java

Comment: You can still use even if your Android project is based on Java

Comment: This library is laggy. When you change the month, you are not able to select a date and if you somehow manage to select the date, it takes up to 2 seconds to select/deselect the date. Also, the default selection is not working in this library.

Comment: @KishanSolanki I did not experience any lagging, can you please elaborate more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this great https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar , it has everything you need.

Here is an example of use

First add this to your xml file

```
<devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar.HorizontalCalendarView
                        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#FAFAFA"
                        app:selectedDateBackground="#00ffffff"
                        app:selectorColor="#c62828"
                        app:textColorNormal="#bababa"
                        app:textColorSelected="@color/blue_color"
                        app:textSizeDayName="20sp"
                        app:textSizeDayNumber="20sp" />
```

Then is your activity declare an instance of `HorizontalCalendar`

```
private HorizontalCalendar horizontalCalendar;
```

Fianally the java code

```
Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

    horizontalCalendar = new HorizontalCalendar.Builder(root, R.id.calendarView)
            .startDate(startDate.getTime())
            .endDate(endDate.getTime())
            .datesNumberOnScreen(5)
            .dayNameFormat("EEE")
            .dayNumberFormat("dd")
            .monthFormat("MMM")
            .textSize(14f, 24f, 14f)
            .showDayName(true)
            .showMonthName(true)

            .build();

    horizontalCalendar.setCalendarListener(new HorizontalCalendarListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(Date date, int position) {
       //Toast.makeText(getContext(), DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date) + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

      });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this library is not maintained for more than 1.5 years. has 50 open issues and valid PRs and is not migrated to use androidx.

Comment: It stays unresolved in the XML  even after adding this 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4' in the gradle